# How do I "add GRADLE_HOME to system variables" in mac?

Tags: macos, gradle, macos-catalina, system-variable

I'm trying to get a repo running, and one of the steps is

```
add GRADLE_HOME to system variables
```

I've already added JAVA_HOME to my path (*I think correctly?*), which was a previous step.

running `nano .bash_profile` shows me the following

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export GRADLE_HOME=$(/usr/local/opt/gradle/libexec)
export PATH=${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

However, `echo $GRADLE_HOME` doesn't return anything and echo `GRADLE_HOME` just returns `GRADLE_HOME`.

I'm not sure if I've successfully added GRADLE_HOME to system variables for my mac.

Comment: How did you install Gradle on your mac?

Comment: Brew install gradle